# Spring rule-ref to bean naviagation in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin

Actually we are using the Spring for the dependency injection for the decorator design pattern.So the beans will be spread across the different XML files. i Need Some tool or plugin in the Eclipse that navigate rule-ref  to the Actual bean location. So analyzing will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing a spring based application I would suggest you to use Spring Tools Suite. I have been using it and makes it easier to navigate across the XML files. Just `cntrl+click` on the `ref` does the magic.

Make sure the the bean configuration files when viewed in eclipse have this icon.

[image: Configuration files have a special icon]

Comment: Create the spring configuration file using this method:

Right clk on the folder -> New -> Other -> Select "Spring bean configuration file"

Then eclipse will be able to recognize it as a Spring Configuration file.

Comment: Actually in same file it will work. If the bean is in different file its not working.